# Angular JS service dependency injection error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise, angular-resource, angular-services

I am new to angular I have been trying to do asynchronous validation for username availability and I am getting "Cannot read property 'userName' of undefined"
Here is my service code

```
webAppServices.factory('services', ['$resource',
function ($resource){
    return{
        users: $resource('http://localhost:8080/api/users',{},{
            get:{method:'GET',isArray:true},
            add:{method:'POST',isArray:false},
            update:{method:'POST',isArray:false}
        }),

       userName:$resource('http://localhost:8080/api/users/check/:username',{},{
            check:{method:'GET',isArray:false}
        })
    };}]);
```

Here is my directive code which passes username for validation

```
webAppValidation.directive('checkUsername', ['services',
function ($q, services) {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$asyncValidators.checkUsername = function(modelValue, viewValue){
               //check username
                return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) || services.userName.check({username:modelValue}).
                        then(function resolved(){
                            //username exists, this means validation fails
                            return $q.reject('exists');
                        }, function rejected(){
                            //username does not exists, therefore this validation passes
                            return true;
                        });
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

And this is what I am getting in Console

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userName' of undefined
at link.ctrl.$asyncValidators.checkUsername (validations.js:56)
at angular.js:24723
at forEach (angular.js:350)
at processAsyncValidators (angular.js:24722)
at NgModelController.$$runValidators (angular.js:24681)
at NgModelController.$$parseAndValidate (angular.js:24819)
at NgModelController.$commitViewValue (angular.js:24787)
at angular.js:24920
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:15719)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15818)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not injecting the `$q` service.

```
webAppValidation.directive('checkUsername', ['$q','services', ...
```

I would write it like this

```
webAppServices.factory('usersService', ['$q','$http',

  var endPoint = 'http://localhost:8080/api/user';

  function ($q, $http){
    var _getUsers = function(){
       var deffered = $q.defer();

       $http.get(endpoint)
            .then(
              function(data){ deffered.resolve(data);}),
              function(data){ deffered.reject(data);})
            ).catch(function(error){  $q.reject(error);});

       deffered.promise;

 }
 //...
 //the other methods
 //...
    return{
       getUsers: _getUsers
       //...
    }
;}]);
```

Although `$http` returns a promise, is better to return with `$q` a thenable object to follow the specifications of promises, so the users of your services didnt be confused seeing `then ... undefined`

Comment: thanks @AvraamMavridis that solved the undefined problem now I am getting
TypeError: services.userName.check(...).then is not a function
    at link.ctrl.$asyncValidators.checkUsername (validations.js:56)
angular.js:10413 GET http://localhost:8080/api/users/check/j 404 (Not Found)

Comment: you should use `success` instead of `then`

Comment: @AvraamMavridis are you serious..$resource ever provide `success ` method?

Comment: @pankajparkar sorry, didnt spot that is` $resource` instead of `$http`

Comment: @JigarJoshi its problem inside a factory end look below answer

Comment: @JigarJoshi Although `$resource` can solve your problem I suggest you to use the `$http` service, is more flexible and you have more options to parametrise it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `webservice` should be exposing those function, it should return `$resource` object that will return a promise. For reutrning promise you need to use `$resource.$promise` so that the promise chain will continue.

**Service**

```
webAppServices.factory('services', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return {
            users: function() {
                return $resource('http://localhost:8080/api/users', {}, {
                    get: {
                        method: 'GET',
                        isArray: true
                    },
                    add: {
                        method: 'POST',
                        isArray: false
                    },
                    update: {
                        method: 'POST',
                        isArray: false
                    }
                }).$promise; //returning promise
            },

            userName: function() {
                return $resource('http://localhost:8080/api/users/check/:username', {}, {
                    check: {
                        method: 'GET',
                        isArray: false
                    }
                }).$promise; //returning promise
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

then do inject missing `$q` inside your service.

```
webAppValidation.directive('checkUsername', ['$q', 'services',
function ($q, services) {
```

Comment: Order of your injection is wrong, you've mapped `$q` to `services` and `services` to `$q`

Comment: @pankajparkar, this still doesn't work it gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'check' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping, Its working now,
I had to inject '$q' and add $promise in my validation directive

```
webAppValidation.directive('checkUsername', ['$q','services',
function ($q, services) {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$asyncValidators.checkUsername = function(modelValue, viewValue){
               //check username
                return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) || services.userName.check({username:modelValue}).
                        $promise.then(function resolved(){
                            //username exists, this means validation fails
                            return $q.reject('exists');
                        }, function rejected(){
                            //username does not exists, therefore this validation passes
                            return true;
                        });
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```